# Saved changes to grub doesnt actually work when booting

Tags: boot, grub2, gedit

So I have a problem of PCIe bus error , its due to my hardware . The workaround i found was to put pci=noaer inside grub file beside quiet splash ( in the line that starts with linux) but as of now i have to edit the grub file every time i boot up or else i still see the error ( I think pi=noaer probably doesnt show and save me the logs of PCIe bus error ) . So i tried to change my grub in the OS , and after doing that i saved it . and got the following warning :

`(gedit:6134): Tepl-WARNING **: 08:49:49.614: GVfs metadata is not supported. Fallback to TeplMetadataManager. Either GVfs is not correctly installed or GVfs metadata are not supported on this platform. In the latter case, you should configure Tepl with --disable-gvfs-metadata.`

`

also after that the termial was unusable , i couldnt really execute any commands ( is it because the previous process was still running ?)

anyway , the workaround for this warning was to use

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

but even on using it i find the same warning.

But the main problem is that , when i open the file , i can see that it has pci=noaer already written on it , perhaps i need to use sudo update-grub?

But on doing that ( ie sudo update-grub) I get this

```
`Sourcing file '/etc/default/grub'

/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: r#: not found `
```

So what do i do now? or is it done ?